# IIS and Helicon ISAPI each request runs twice

Tags: iis, isapi, isapi-rewrite

under IIS I have installed ISAPI Rewrite Build 81 now I have a problem that almost each request runs twice.
But in my test environment IIS + Helicon ISAPI Bild 47 I don't have such problem.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you don’t have double-registration issue: http://www.helicontech.com/articles/isapi_rewrite-double-registration/
Check if Build 81 is the only version of ISAPI_Rewrite installed on the system.